# Primefaces action is not fired in datagrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following Primefaces 3.5 page where I defined two commandLink. My problem is that action of `lockout` is not fired (checked with breakpoint) although `lockoutTest` with the same setting works. `oncomplete` works on both commandLink No exception is thrown.

```
<p:dataTable id="calendar" value="#{calendarView.calendarData.entrySet().toArray()}" var="row">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandLink id="lockoutTest"
                                           value="test lockout"
                                           update=":mainForm:lockoutEditorDialog"
                                           process="@this"
                                           action="#{calendarView.editLockout(15,15)}"
                                           oncomplete="lockoutDialogWidget.show()">
                                <f:attribute name="title" value="valami" escape="true" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column style="width: 50px; text-align: right">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msgs.calendar_room}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.key.roomNumber}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:columns value="#{calendarView.columns}" var="column" style="text-align: center; #{not empty row.value[column].color ? 'background-color:#'.concat(row.value[column].color):''}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{column}" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink id="lockout"
                           value="#{row.value[column].text}"
                           update=":mainForm:lockoutEditorDialog"
                           process="@this"
                           action="#{calendarView.editLockout(row.key.roomNumber,column)}"
                           oncomplete="lockoutDialogWidget.show()"
                           rendered="#{row.value[column].text == 'K'}">
                    <f:attribute name="title" value="#{row.value[column].label}" escape="true" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
```

UPDATE:

I've changed `p:columns` to a simple `p:column` for testing and it works:

```
        <p:column id="testcolumn">
            <p:commandLink id="lockouttest"
                           value="T"
                           update=":mainForm:lockoutEditorDialog"
                           process="@this"
                           action="#{calendarView.editLockout(15,15)}"
                           oncomplete="lockoutDialogWidget.show()"
                           >
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
```

Comment: Try to add '<p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>' if that shows you any error messages.

Comment: Also always check for javascript errors.

Comment: p:messages shows nothing, no js errors

Comment: It is strange that oncomplete is called. Are you sure that the action is not called? Breakpoint can fail sometimes and need a clean compile.

Comment: Check if a request has been sent to the server with firebug, check send parameter and the response from server.

Answer (score -1):

Use `actionListener` instead of `action` when you want to call a method in your backing bean.

Also, make sure your `p:commandLink` is placed within a `h:form` (I assume you've ommited it here since it should be a parent of your `p:datatable`)

Comment: Yes, some of the code is omitted. Datatable is placed within h:form

Comment: _"Use actionListener instead of action when you want to call a method in your backing bean."_ ??? Why? action should work to